# Hashmap выдает 0 размер

Tags: java, android, java-hashmap

Первая мапа выдает размер 3, все ок. Но та, которая заполняется из бд, всегда имеет размер 0, повторяющихся ключей и значений нет. Данные из самой бд парсятся нормально.

```
    hashmap.put(1,"1");
    hashmap.put(2,"2");
    hashmap.put(3,"3");
    hashmap.size();

    requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try{
                    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("JUDGES");
                        for (int i=0;i>jsonArray.length();i++){
                            JSONObject judges = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String name = judges.getString("J_NAME");
                            int jid = judges.getInt("ID");
                            hmjudges.put(jid,name);
                            hmjudges.size();
                        }
                }catch (JSONException e){e.printStackTrace();}
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

**UPD** С ArrayList все работает.

```
hashmap.put(1,"1");
    hashmap.put(2,"2");
    hashmap.put(3,"3");
    hashmap.size();
    final List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://full-version.ru/select_judge/judges.php",
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try{
                    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("JUDGES");
                        for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                            JSONObject judges = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String name = judges.getString("J_NAME");
                            int jid = judges.getInt("ID");
                            names.add(name);
                            hmjudges.put(jid,name);
                            hmjudges.size();
                        }
                }catch (JSONException e){e.printStackTrace();}
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Answer (score 2):

Автор опечатался в цикле:

```
for (int i=0;i>jsonArray.length();i++){
```

Правильно будет:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
//             ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Я тоже думал, что ошибся, но как местами не менял - ничего не поменялось)

Comment: @AndrewDmitriev, значит дело в том, что jsonArray пустой или onResponse вообще не вызывался. Добавьте логирование к коде и посмотрите где код выполнялся

Comment: В этом и суть, что String name и int jid заполняются! Добавлял логи и все выводило, но почему-то в мапу не добавляет. В arraylist все отлично добавляется, но добавил hashmap - все перестало работать)

Comment: Тогда, или у вас где-то в коде он очищается, или переинициализируется, да и вы ведь, судя по коду, добавляете в `hmjudges`, а не `hashmap`, может поэтому `hashmap` и пустой? :)

Comment: hmjudges это хэшмэп, который принимает данные из бд, а тот хэшмэп,что сверху, просто для примера, что все работает.

Comment: @AndrewDmitriev и у вас не заполняется `hmjudges`, но при этом метод `onResponse` вызывается, `jsonArray.length()` больше 0, в цикле условие `i < jsonArray.length()` выполняется, и внутри `onResponse` исключение не вызывалось? :)

Comment: Когда начинаю отладку со строки JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("JUDGES"); то все нормально добавляется через раз, омг

Comment: @AndrewDmitriev, добавьте по всему коду Log.debug и смотрите в консоли logcat что выводится, какие данные приходят, в ваш весь код посмотреть я не смогу, поэтому по тому коду что дали свои предположения я сказал